# Omniauth - choose provider dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, rails-api

Say I have a restful resource, `UserSession`

```
> POST /user_sessions.json
{
    "user_session": {
        "user": {
            "some_key": "some_value",
            "some_other_key": "some_other_value"
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to choose the provider in the `UserSessions#create` based on the params supplied, rather than using the `/auth/:provider` OmniAuth normally uses. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am using a technique to set some omniauth options into the user-session.

i guess that this might work for your solution as well. you still have use the `/auth/:provider` routes though!

so i am basically linking all login urls to my `auth_path`

```
# routes.rb
get '/auth/login/:provider',          to: 'sessions#auth',     as: :auth
```

once i extract the data and put it into the session, i redirect the user to the right login path. in your case, it would need to extract the data from the params and then redirect:

```
# sessions_controller.rb
def auth
  session[:omniauth_keys] = Usergroup.omniauth_keys(params[:provider], request)
  redirect_to "/auth/#{params[:provider]}"
end
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Seeing this also helped understand how the session hash is used: https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby/blob/9285bd6d73602c5765a560ff3347ce2632be7058/config/initializers/omniauth.rb